# if_else across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, ggmap

I'm using a function (mutate_geocode) that outputs two columns of data, longitude and latitude. Because google api costs money in large quantities, I only want it to run the geocode function on areas that I do NOT already have the longitude and latitude.

```
library(dplyr)
problem <- tibble(location = c("Atlanta United States", "Paris France", "Rome Italy"),
lon = c(NA, 2.35, 12.49),
lat = c(NA, 48.86, 41.90))
```

And I want it to ultimately look like this (again, WITHOUT running the geocode over the areas that I already have:

```
library(dplyr)
solution <- tibble(location = c("Atlanta United States", "Paris France", "Rome Italy"),
lon = c(-84.39, 2.35, 12.49),
lat = c(33.75, 48.86, 41.90))
```

To get there, I've tried using if_else, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
solution <- if_else(is.na(problem$lon) & is.na(problem$lat), true = mutate_geocode(problem$location), false = c(problem$lon & problem$lat))
```

I'm open to solutions and appreciate your time! If you could also explain your code, that will help me in the future as well. Thank you!

Comment: Unlikely to happen, perhaps, but you might be a little more resilient with "or" instead of "and" when checking `is.na` on the lat/lon: having just one is typically not helpful, unless you are potentially identifying things like the equator and prime meridian.

Answer (score 2):

Like `base::ifelse`, `dplyr::if_else` requires the result to be the "same shape" as the test argument. Your test is just a vector of a single column, so the results need to be a vector of a single column. Since your results are a different shape, `if_else` is a bad tool for the job.

Just run `mutate_geocode` on the missing subset of data:

```
is_missing = is.na(problem$lon) & is.na(problem$lat)  ## maybe you want `|` instead?
problem[is_missing , c("lon", "lat")] = mutate_geocode(problem[is_missing , "location"])
```

Comment: thanks for your help! However, when I run the third line of code, I receive an error: Error in geocode(locs, ...) : is.character(location) is not TRUE

Comment: @J.Sabree, then you have `factor`s in your data. `as.character` might be your friend here. (Your example does not have `factor`s, btw.)

Comment: Sounds like your `location` column isn't a `character` class, but it needs to be. Try `problem$location = as.character(problem$location)`

Comment: @r2evans and Gregor,  I used glimpse(problem) and location is character. I still ran the as character code, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I've never used `mutate_geocode`, but the example I see in the documentation looks like this: `mutate_geocode(df, address)`, where the data frame is the first argument, and the column is the second argument. The way we are calling it, we just want to call it on specific values, so I think if you use `geocode()` instead of `mutate_geocode()` that should solve your problem.